# Does an LED TV that is displaying "black" emit enough light to trigger an LDR?

Tags: led, ldr

I would like to monitor a digital sign to make sure it stays 'online' - the setup is a Raspberry Pi connected via HDMI to an LED TV. I have seen some general linux discussion about polling HDMI-attached devices but have not not yet been able to get this working. Since the GPIO pins exist can I just use a "physical" solution and check to see if the TV is on and producing output by taping a small LDR to the corner of the screen?

One caveat is that the slideshow has a black background, and so I'm wondering if there will be enough "light" from this to definitively register the difference between "on" and "off" with the LDR.

I just ordered some cheap LDR's and am planning to taking some readings when they arrive, but am I headed in the right direction? If not, what are some options I could use instead of an LDR?

Comment: Is there a "power on" LED?

Comment: Why not put the LDR inside the casing next to the backlight?

Comment: Have you control of the contents of the slideshow? Could you arrange for there to be a small white area which will be under the LDR?

Comment: three very good ideas - thanks! spehro - could it tell the difference between amber / red / green? ignacgio - maybe the trouble of taking it apart? gbulmer - it did cross my mind before but i still think it would be nice if it could read the "black" on vs off

Comment: LDRs are a dime a dozen. With an led, transistor, a few resistors/pots and a battery, you can quickly figure this out.

Comment: How will this work in the daytime?

Comment: There must be a fair number of pins/ports/points on the internal PCB's that are only live when the TV is on. You may be able to detect voltage on pins of any of the external input connections (HDMI, SCART, even headphones maybe?), failing that things like the backlight or any connection to the screen I'd only expect to be powered when the TV is fully ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, what are some options I could use instead of an LDR?

Monitoring something does not mean there is a mechanism to "make sure it stays 'online' " - that needs some form of interaction with a control but, assuming you mean you just want to detect if it goes off-line then, why not monitor the AC current it takes - if it goes off-line, almost for sure the current taken down its power cable will reduce significantly and this, in the case of an AC power feed, is easy to do with a current transformer on either the live or neutral wire. It could also be done with a hall effect sensor and this would work if the power source is DC.

Answer (score 0):

If the brightness of your TV is not set to the maximum, and the backlighting is driven with PWM (which is the case on many TVs, but not necessarily all of them), then you should  be able to detect the PWM frequency using a photodiode, a band-pass filter and an amplifier. If the detector is close enough to the screen, you should be able to detect the PWM even with a black screen.

However, as many of the comments point out, there might be other solutions that are easier to realize (e.g., getting a voltage on the SCART, video output, headphones, etc.).